# Query to pull all unique indexes from all tables in database using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unique-index

Query to pull all unique indexes from all tables in database using sql. The output should display schema name, table name and column name.

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT
     t.[name] AS TableName
    ,i.[name] AS IndexName
    ,c.[name] AS ColumnName
FROM sys.schemas s
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    AND s.[name] = 'dbo'
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = t.object_id
    AND i.index_id > 0
    AND i.is_primary_key = 0
    AND i.is_unique = 1
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = t.object_id
    AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
```

but it displays `TableName` and `IndexName` multiple times if they have more than one unique index column.

It want to display:

```
TableName   IndexName           ColumnName
Customers   IX_customer_name    FirstName, LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sp_MSforEachDB` stored procedure:

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb '
USE [?];
select db_name(), *
from sys.indexes
where is_unique = 1';
```

You can also exclude system databases by adding `if db_id() > 4 begin end`.